# OpenGL draw dashed line does not work when line width is small

Tags: c++, opengl

I use the following test code to draw a dashed line with OpenGL.

```
glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_LINE_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT);
    glLineWidth(1.4);
    glColor3ub(7, 7, 7);
    glLineStipple( 1, 0x0F0F );
    glEnable( GL_LINE_STIPPLE );
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glVertex2d(x0, y0);
        glVertex2d(x1, y1);
    glEnd();
glPopAttrib()
```

The strange thing is that when I set the line width less than 1.5 the dashed line became solid. When the line width is greater or equal than 1.5, the dashed line is rendered as expected. why is that?
This happens on Ubuntu 12.04. But the codes works fine with Windows OS.

Comment: Is Ubuntu using GPU hardware? If not, Mesa emulation would behave different as the GPU driver.

Comment: Yes, it's hardware accelerated.